# Creating ChatBot from custom Knowledge Base using ChatGPT

Tags: chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, openai-api, azure-openai

**Problem Description:**

We have a strong and huge Knowledge Base internally for our organization which contains a lot of documentation, policies and guidelines, tutorials, question answers, employee's helpful forms and documents like leave form or onboarding document and so on. We want to have a ChatBot which can read and analyze the information from the Knowledge Base and respond to user queries with meaningful answer without letting the user to go through whole KB article or the document. For example,

**User:** How many annual leaves I can take as a permanent employee?

**Bot:** You can take 21 calendar leaves in an year apart of 5 sick leaves.

While the Bot's answer could be written on a page in the leaves policy document in the Knowledge Base. So basically, we want to get our site crawled and have a bot to answer the user queries instantly.

**My Research:**
As per my research so far, below could be the possibility using Azure OpenAI and Azure Cognitive Search.  Since I do not have experience in human language processing or using ChatGPT services from a developer perspective, I am not very sure that if the purposed solution will actually fit in to my requirements. In this regard, I also found below video which gave me more hope.

[Azure Search OpenAI Demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo)

[ChatGPT & OpenAI powering your apps | OpenAI Studio in Microsoft Azure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3t3qZu1Dy1k&t=572s&ab_channel=MicrosoftMechanics)

**Question:**

Will the above solution work in this case?

What could be the other possible ways to achieve this with minimum development effort?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the Retrieval Augmented Generation pattern. Look at this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo which is built around Azure Search (for the knowledge base) and Azure OpenAI.

Comment: This is the same what i mentioned in my question. I have already shortlisted this option but i am also looking for new ideas.